# Background and font style not changing

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

Why my header background not changing to red and font style not changing to coiny?

**index.js**

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen h-full w-full flex flex-col bg-brand-light overflow-hidden">
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main className='bg-red-700'>
        <h1 className='font-coiny'>
          Welcome to <a href="https://nextjs.org">Next.js!</a>
        </h1>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        coiny: ['Coiny', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans]
      },
    }, colors: {
      'brand-purple': 'var(--clr-purple)',
      'brand-pink': 'var(--clr-pink)',
      'brand-yellow': 'var(--clr-yellow)',
      'brand-blue': 'var(--clr-blue)',
      'brand-green': 'var(--clr-green)',
      'brand-light': 'var(--clr-light)',
      'brand-background': 'var(--clr-background)'
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**global.css**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Coiny&family=Open+Sans:wght@400;500;600&display=swap');

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

:root {
  --font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  --clr-light: #f0e9e9;
  --clr-purple: #9b5de5;
  --clr-pink: #f15bb5;
  --clr-yellow: #fee440;
  --clr-blue: #00bbf9;
  --clr-green: #00f5d4;
  --clr-selection-bg: #cb3d92;
  --clr-selection-text: #f4f0f0;
  --clr-background: #06070a;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  font-family: var(--font-family);
  background: var(--clr-background);
}

::selection {
  background: var(--clr-selection-bg);
  color: var(--clr-selection-text);
}
```

**_app.js**

```
import '../styles/globals.css'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "nft-minting-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "13.0.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
  }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change the tailwind.config.js to

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx,tsx,ts}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        coiny: ['Coiny', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans]
      },  colors: {
        'brand-purple': 'var(--clr-purple)',
        'brand-pink': 'var(--clr-pink)',
        'brand-yellow': 'var(--clr-yellow)',
        'brand-blue': 'var(--clr-blue)',
        'brand-green': 'var(--clr-green)',
        'brand-light': 'var(--clr-light)',
        'brand-background': 'var(--clr-background)'
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

This is because you are utilizing typescript (TSX) while you have not added that the content to the tailwind config file.

Comment: I added in content but still same.

Comment: Could you please display the _app.{js,ts} and the package.json? I think with that, I or others could triangulate the problem more accurately.

Comment: post edited..I have change TSX file to .js, but the font style and header backgroud still same.